# Eclipse Mars: Unhandled event loop exception

Tags: java, eclipse

***I've been trying to set up Eclipse Mars on Windows 7 (64-bit). When I start up and load my workspace I'm greeted with a lovely Problem Occured message saying Unhandled event loop exception. No more handles. Below is my exception stack trace.***

```
    org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4517)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4406)
at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4377)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.error(Widget.java:482)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.createHandle(Control.java:703)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label.createHandle(Label.java:199)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.createWidget(Control.java:743)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.<init>(Control.java:111)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label.<init>(Label.java:101)
at org.eclipse.ui.texteditor.StatusLineContributionItem.fill(StatusLineContributionItem.java:182)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.SubContributionItem.fill(SubContributionItem.java:58)
at org.eclipse.jface.action.StatusLineManager.update(StatusLineManager.java:290)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.updateActivations(WorkbenchPage.java:305)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$18(WorkbenchPage.java:283)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$E4PartListener.partActivated(WorkbenchPage.java:201)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl$3.run(PartServiceImpl.java:245)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.firePartActivated(PartServiceImpl.java:242)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:711)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.PartServiceImpl.activate(PartServiceImpl.java:639)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.AbstractPartRenderer.activate(AbstractPartRenderer.java:106)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer$1.handleEvent(ContributedPartRenderer.java:63)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.sendEvent(Display.java:4362)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1113)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1137)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1122)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.setActiveControl(Shell.java:1481)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.WM_MOUSEACTIVATE(Shell.java:2377)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4720)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:339)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Decorations.windowProc(Decorations.java:1633)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell.windowProc(Shell.java:2117)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5063)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:86)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4774)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5063)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:86)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4774)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5063)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:86)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4774)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5063)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:86)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4774)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5063)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:86)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4774)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5063)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:86)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4774)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5063)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:86)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4774)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5063)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:86)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4774)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5063)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:86)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4774)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5063)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:86)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4774)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5063)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:86)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4774)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5063)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:86)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4774)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5063)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:86)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4774)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5063)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:86)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4774)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5063)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:86)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4774)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:339)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5063)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProcW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.DefWindowProc(OS.java:2544)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Scrollable.callWindowProc(Scrollable.java:86)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:4774)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Canvas.windowProc(Canvas.java:339)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5063)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.PeekMessageW(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.swt.internal.win32.OS.PeekMessage(OS.java:3141)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3764)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1127)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1018)
at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:156)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:654)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:337)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:598)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:139)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:380)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:235)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:669)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:608)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1515)
```